# Creating a text file in ipad application

Tags: ipad

How to create a file and save it as a text file in iPad through the application?. If I had to read that file at a later stage how to specify the absolute path. Could some one help on this.

Is it possible to display the text file created using the iPad app in the device homescreen, so that user's will be able to modify it.

Comment: I can give you can concret answer for this question. You can create a txt file in an ipad application but you cannot put it on home screen for user to edit it.

Comment: If so how to create and access the text file could you please give me a code snippet. That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To Write a file to documents directory use following code, (you may need to do some syntax correction as not tested)

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir =[documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:yourFileName];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];

// Open a handle to it.
NSFileHandle* pfile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];

[pfile writeData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"YourData"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

And to provide user facility to edit it you can use, one option I can see.

Enable `"Application supports iTunes file sharing"`in plist file of the application so that user would be able to see the documents through the itunes.

You need to read and check the content though to track the changes done to document.